# Continuous predictors for negative binomial regression

Tags: categorical-data, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, continuous-data

I can't seem to find a straight answer for this question. From formal coursework I've taken, it seems that Poisson/negative binomial regression require a data layout like this:
[image: Data layout in SAS]
Where the categorical value of age forces a new observation for each category, such that you have count totals that fall into each age group which will then add up to the total counts. You also have binary variables that indicate which age category the counts for that group belong to.

Requiring this data layout seems to show that categorical predictor variables are required. 
My questions are:

1.) Is there a way to analyze continuous predictor variables without categorizing them?

2.) Does the data layout differ across different software types?

I'm not concerned with how to code the data, so I posted it in cross validated instead of stack overflow. However, I found this question to fall in between the topics of both.

Comment: Is your concern that using a continuous predictor could wind up with a predicted value that isn't an integer which makes no sense for a count variable?

Comment: Perhaps, but would rounding the predicted value be applicable? From what I have seen, categorical data must be used and the layout should be as shown in the attached picture.

Comment: It's fine to get a non-integer value. Remember the link function; you raise $e$ to whatever value your regression equation gives to find the predicted value, anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have an example of how the data layout would look in this case? Would you still need to have a new observation for each unique value of age?

Comment: It would be the same as for a linear regression but with counts in the column for the response variable.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you so much.